# images upload issue: zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload

while uploading the image having spaces in its name gives an error Message:

```
An unknown error has occurred.
```

Here is the code of form :

```
    $resizeRename = new Zend_Form_Element_File('renameResize');
    $resizeRename->setDestination('images/fbAppLogo');
    $resizeRename->setLabel('Upload App Logo');
    $resizeRename->addFilter(new Skoch_Filter_File_Resize(array(
        'width' => 111,
        'height' => 74,
        'keepRatio' => true,
    )));  
    $resizeRename->setAttrib('class','tooltip');
    $resizeRename->setAttrib('title','Upload file');   
    $this->addElement($resizeRename);

        here is the code of my controller:-
           if ($form->isValid($data)) {
                             $file=pathinfo($form->renameResize->getFileName());
                             if($form->renameResize->receive()) {
               $this->view->renameResize=pathinfo($form->renameResize->getFileName());
                             }
                       }
```

above code is working fine if images name contain no spaces.

Comment: Did you tried escaping the spaces?

Comment: I have renamed the file $file=pathinfo($form->renameResize->getFileName());
$file['basename']=str_replace(" ", "-",$file['basename']); 
$file['filename']=str_replace(" ", "-",$file['filename']);

but $form->renameResize->getFileName() didnt gives me the renamed name of the file
$this->view->renameResize=pathinfo($form->renameResize->getFileName());

Comment: I am new to zend will u please help me

Comment: hey i have made the changes and now its working fine :)
        if($form->renameResize->isUploaded()) {
    $file= pathinfo($form->renameResize->getFileName());
    $newFilename = time() . '.' . $file['extension'];
    $form->renameResize->addFilter('Rename', "images/fbAppLogo/" .$newFilename,$file['basename']);
    $form->renameResize->receive();
 }